# How to use zsh without affecting others?

Tags: zsh

I have installed oh-my-zsh in a remote machine and powerline fonts in local PC. This mean if I use zsh, the special characters will not display correctly in other people's terminal.

How to make zsh serve only for me and others use the default one?

Comment: you and others are using same user?

Comment: Yes, we use the same account.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to switch to zsh, `chsh -s /bin/zsh` will set zsh as default then every user should use it, `zsh` will change shell to zsh only this time this connection. So the second way is just fine.

For these having similar problem, I write an alias

```
alias ssh_alias='ssh -p 1234 -i path/to/id_rsa name@host -t '\''zsh'\'
```

[ref](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/8147)